# ¿Cómo evitar impresión en notación científica de un número?

Tags: php

Imprimir ciertos números hace que aparezcan en notación científica, p.e.:

```
<?php

echo 0.0000000001;
echo (float) 0.0000000001;
echo (string) 0.0000000001;
```

Da siempre, cómo resultado (PHP 7.4.33, 8.0.30, 8.1.22, 8.2.9):

```
1.0E-10
```

¿Se puede evitar y mostrar el número tal cuál?

Comment: Puedes formatear con [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php). Ej.: `echo sprintf("%.10f",0.0000000001);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el "number_format()", ya sea solo, con float o string respetando los decimales.

Aqui el codigo:

```php
<?php

$numero = 0.0000000001;

echo number_format($numero, 10); 
echo "\n";

echo number_format((float) $numero, 10); 
echo "\n";

echo number_format((string) $numero, 10);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Cabría añadir que lo que buscaba era imprimir en *notación decimal* y al usar `number_format`indicando la base 10, incluso pasando el número con la notación científica se imprimirá en notación decimal, p.e. `echo number_format(8E-08, 10);  // 0.0000000800`